# Display the Content in TabContainer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, infowindow, chart

I have two tabs on my Info Window Popup. My code is based on the sample ArcGIS API for JavaScript Sandbox.

The only change compared to this sample is: I want to display pie charts on both the tabs. The issue I am facing is:

The tab1 is selected when the popup appears but its content is not displayed. But if I click the tab2, the content (pie chart) is displayed. If I click the tab1 after I click the tab2, the pie chart in tab1 is displayed at this time.

I am trying to get the pie chart displayed in tab1 when the user clicks the feature layer on the map.

How can I fix the issue? Somebody please help me out with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Pie Chart</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .chart {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        padding:0 !important;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    // Try other themes: Julie, CubanShirts, PrimaryColors, Charged, BlueDusk, Bahamation, Harmony, Shrooms, Minty, Tom
    var theme = "PrimaryColors";
    require([
        "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/dijit/InfoWindow", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/dijit/Popup",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
        "dojox/charting/Chart2D", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
        "dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight", "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice", "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
        "dojox/charting/themes/" + theme,
        "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/dom-class",
        "dojo/number", "dojo/parser","dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
            Map, FeatureLayer,
            InfoWindow, InfoTemplate, Popup,
            SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleRenderer,
            ContentPane, TabContainer,
            Chart2D, Pie,
            Highlight, MoveSlice, Tooltip,
            dojoxTheme,
            domConstruct, domClass,
            number, parser
    ) {

        parser.parse();
        // Use the info window instead of the popup.
        var infoWindow = new InfoWindow(null, domConstruct.create("div"));
        infoWindow.startup();

        map = new Map("map", {
            basemap: "topo",
            center: [-113.405, 43.521],
            infoWindow: infoWindow,
            zoom: 5
        });
        map.infoWindow.resize(275, 275);

        var template = new esri.InfoTemplate();
        template.setTitle("<b>${Instl_Name}</b>");
        template.setContent(getWindowContent);

        var layer = new FeatureLayer("RESTUrlEndpoints/FeatureServer/0", {
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
            infoTemplate: template,
            outFields: ["*"]
        });

        map.addLayer(layer);

        function getWindowContent(graphic) {
            // Make a tab container.
            var tc = new TabContainer({
                style: "width:100%;height:100%;"
            }, domConstruct.create("div"));

            // Display 1st pie chart.
            var cp1 = new ContentPane({
                title: "Collection"
            });
            tc.addChild(cp1);

            var c1 = domConstruct.create("div",{
                id: "Collection"
            }, domConstruct.create("div"));
            var chart1 = new Chart2D(c1);
            domClass.add(chart1, "chart1");

            chart1.setTheme(dojoxTheme);
            chart1.addPlot("default", {
                type: "Pie",
                radius: 70,
                htmlLabels: true
            });

            tc.watch("selectedChildWidget", function(name, oldVal, newVal) {
                if (newVal.title === "Collection") {
                    chart1.resize(180, 180);
                }
            });

            // Calculate percent complete/ incomplete.
            var total1 = 100;
            var complete_collection = number.round(graphic.attributes.Data_Collection);
            var incomplete_collection = total1 - complete_collection;
            chart1.addSeries("% Complete", [{
                y: incomplete_collection,
                tooltip: incomplete_collection,
                text: "% Incomplete",
                color: "red"
            }, {

                y: complete_collection,
                tooltip: complete_collection,
                text: "% Complete",
                color: "green"
            }]);
            //highlight the chart and display tooltips when you mouse over a slice.
            new Highlight(chart1, "default");
            new Tooltip(chart1, "default");
            new MoveSlice(chart1, "default");

            cp1.set("content", chart1.node);

            // Display a dojo pie chart for the complete/incomplete percentage.
            var cp2 = new ContentPane({
                title: "Processing"
            });

            tc.addChild(cp2);

            // Create the chart that will display in the second tab.
            var c = domConstruct.create("div", {
                id: "Processing"
            }, domConstruct.create("div"));
            var chart = new Chart2D(c);
            domClass.add(chart, "chart");

            // Apply a color theme to the chart.
            chart.setTheme(dojoxTheme);
            chart.addPlot("default", {
                type: "Pie",
                radius: 70,
                htmlLabels: true
            });
            tc.watch("selectedChildWidget", function(name, oldVal, newVal) {
                if (newVal.title === "Processing") {
                    chart.resize(180, 180);
                }
            });

            // Calculate percent complete/ incomplete.
            var total = 100;
            var complete_processing = number.round(graphic.attributes.Data_Development);
            var incomplete = total - complete_processing;
            chart.addSeries("% Complete", [{
                y: incomplete,
                tooltip: incomplete,
                text: "% Incomplete",
                color: "red"
            }, {

                y: complete_processing,
                tooltip: complete_processing,
                text: "% Complete",
                color: "green"
            }]);
            //highlight the chart and display tooltips when you mouse over a slice.
            new Highlight(chart, "default");
            new Tooltip(chart, "default");
            new MoveSlice(chart, "default");

            // cp1.set("content", chart.node);
            cp2.set("content", chart.node);

            return tc.domNode;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my experience:
  select all the child in the tabcontainer's loop.
and set every tab content as below:

```
          for(i=0;i<  tc.getChildren().length;i++)
        {
            var subTab = dijit.byId( tc.getChildren()[i].id);
            tc.selectChild(subTab);
            subTab.set("content", grids[i]);

        }
```